# Change html text input value using javascript

Tags: javascript

how do you change text input value in html using javascript? In my case I want to change the price input of an item when the user selects the item and inputs the quantity, for example:

```
<html>
...
<body>
Quantity : <input type="text" id="qty"/>
<br/>
Item : <select id="item" onClick="checkPrice()"><option value="apple">Apple</option><option value="orange">Orange</option></select> //added onClick
<br/>
Price : <input type="text" id="price"/>
</body>
</html>
```

what i would like is when the user input the quantity and item, the price would be automatically inputted.

i have tried this and it inputted NaN (not a number)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkPrice()
{
var a = document.getElementById("item").value;
var b = document.getElementById("qty").value;
if(a = "apple"){
price = 5
document.getElementById("price").value=b*price
}else if(a = "orange"){
price = 4
document.getElementById("price").value=b*price
}
}
</script>
```

Help please? Thank you.

Comment: `a = "apple"` should be `a == "apple"` or `a === "apple"`. I cannot see why would you get `NaN` though.

Comment: well, i have tried using == and === too and it came out NaN

Comment: Well, `if (a = "apple")` is definitely wrong. This will always evaluate to true because a non-empty string is true. If you fix that and call the function on change of the select, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/H74HG/.

Comment: @RendySetiadi the problem is that you're multiplying with a string. That string may contain non-number values, and therefore result in NaN when calculations are performed using it. If the input for `qty` is not a number, then the result of the calculation won't be either. You should make your inputs `type="number"` by the way.

Comment: @joeytje50: Partly true. It's perfectly valid to multiple a string with a number, e.g. `'5' * 5` works fine, but `'5foo' * 5` doesn't.

Comment: You would only get `NaN` if you type non-numeric characters in the `qty` field. Try it in my demo above.

Comment: You updated your code a couple of times. The **only** problem that there is in this code is that you are using `=` instead of `==` or `===`.

Comment: @FelixKling I said that the string may contain non-number values and then result in NaN. So, if the string has a non-number value it will be NaN. I didn't say operations on strings won't work in general.

Comment: yes, the problem is solved using == and changing the input type to number. thanks.

Comment: @joeytje50: Yes, that's what I said as well :) I just wanted to clarify on *"the problem is that you're multiplying with a string."*. The problem is not that it is a string, but that it may contain non-numeric characters.

Comment: @RendySetiadi: Again, as you can see in my demo, it even works without `type="number"`. But at least you got it solved now.

Answer (score 0):

You are multiplying the item by the price, you should be multiplying the "qty" input element by the price.

Also, your if comparison needs an additional equal sign.  You also need something to call the Javascript function.  Here is the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/GmA3v/

```
Quantity : <input type="text" id="qty">
<br/>
Item : <select id="item"><option value="apple">Apple</option><option value="orange">Orange</option></select>
<br/>
Price : <input type="text" id="price">
<p>
<input type = "button" value = "Calculate" onclick="checkPrice()">

<script type="text/javascript">
function checkPrice()
{
    var a = document.getElementById("item").value;

    if(a == "apple")
    {
        var price = 5
        document.getElementById("price").value=document.getElementById("qty").value*price
    }
    else if(a == "orange")
    {
        var price = 4
        document.getElementById("price").value=document.getElementById("qty").value*price
    }
}
</script>
```

I added a button that says "Calculate" that will call the JS function.

Comment: I think you looked at the old code. The OP updated it and it shows that he multiples `price` with the value of `qty`.

Comment: I'm just saying that your explanation of the problem doesn't match with the code in the question.

Comment: I fixed the issues that he has in his code, including his original code before he took the suggestion to fix the quantity problem.

Comment: thanks but i do not need a button, onclick parameter would suffice.

Comment: I think you should use a drop down instead of a text field for the quantity, and then use onchange instead.  That way scrubbing the input for numbers is easier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `checkPrice()` and you were multiplying `a` which was string by a number `price`. `price` was also never initialized.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JyvxL/

```
Quantity : <input type="text" id="qty" />
<br/>
Item : <select id="item"><option value="apple">Apple</option><option value="orange">Orange</option></select>
<br/>
Price : <input type="text" id="price"/>

<script>
 function checkPrice()
 {
    var item = document.getElementById("item").value;
    var a = document.getElementById("qty").value;  
    var price = 0;
    if(item == "apple"){
       price = 5;
       document.getElementById("price").value=a*price;
    }else if(item == "orange"){
       price = 4;
       document.getElementById("price").value=a*price;
    }
}
</script>

<button onclick="checkPrice()">Check price</button>
```

Comment: Semicolons are optional. The absence doesn't explain the error. And in which case would `price` not be initialized? He always assigns a value to it before he uses it.

Comment: @FelixKling Yes, semicolons are optional. While `price` gets a value, it is never technically initialized by `var price`, which is bad practice.

Comment: Not in javascript, which uses hoisting.

Comment: @L0j1k: Hoisting doesn't take place here. `price` will become a global variable. Hoisting only applies to `var foo` declarations.

Comment: It's bad practice, but it is not the reason why the OP would see NaN. I understand that there are many things "wrong" with the code, but those are not the reasons for the problems the OP is facing.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `onchange()` events to the elements, which means that when the `value` of an element changes, javascript will fire the `checkPrice()` function, which updates your values automatically. Also, you are using the assignment operator (`=`) to compare values in your `if()` statement, when you should be using the equality operator (`==`). I have corrected this in the code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function checkPrice()
  {
    if(document.getElementById("item").value == "apple"){
      price = 5
      document.getElementById("price").value=document.getElementById("qty").value*price
    }else if(document.getElementById("item").value == "orange"){
      price = 4
      document.getElementById("price").value=document.getElementById("qty").value*price
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("qty").onchange = checkPrice();
  document.getElementById("item").onchange = checkPrice();
</script>
</head>
<body>
Quantity : <input type="text" id="qty" />
<br/>
Item : <select id="item"><option value="apple">Apple</option><option value="orange">Orange</option></select>
<br/>
Price : <input type="text" id="price"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an associative array to store the relationship between items and their price.

You can also store a reference to the elements outside the scope of the function so you only have to find them once.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZH2Ub/)

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var prices = {
               apple: 5,
               orange: 4
             },
    itemElement,
    qtyElement,
    priceElement,
    checkPrice = function(){
        priceElement.value = parseInt( ( qtyElement.value || 0 ) )
                             * (prices[ itemElement.value ] || 0 );
    };

window.onload = function(){
    itemElement  = document.getElementById("item");
    qtyElement   = document.getElementById("qty");
    priceElement = document.getElementById("price");
    checkPrice();
};
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
Quantity : <input type="text" id="qty" onchange="javascript:checkPrice()" />
<br/>
Item : <select id="item" onchange="javascript:checkPrice()">
            <option value="apple">Apple</option>
            <option value="orange">Orange</option>
</select>
<br/>
Price : <input type="text" id="price" readonly="readOnly" />
```

Answer (score -2):

If you prefer a nice clean jQuery solution:

Add the price for each item with `data-`

`<option value="apple" data-price="2">Apple</option>`

```
var getPrice = function(){
  var qty = $('#qty').val();
  var cost = $('#item').find('option:selected').attr('data-price');
  var price = Math.floor(qty*cost);
  $('#price').attr('value',price);
}
$('#qty').on('keydown input',getPrice)
$('#item').on('change',getPrice)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7vTF2/1/

Comment: As popular as this one is I think it's a valid option. It still outlines the essentials and I didn't have to break a sweat. Javascript is gone (like the dinosaurs), but we'll use it for a long time (like petroleum).

Comment: The javascript tag description says: *"Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."*.

Comment: Uhh. jQuery is written in javascript (duh). Your code adds an extra request or cache call AND an unspecified amount of code to work. AND the user did not say he wanted a jQuery/framework answer.

Comment: Yes yes, and petroleum is refined from fossils. Some people prefer to walk, some to drive. Guess who gets there faster. Plenty of other non-framework solutions to choose from, but for this particular libary, I see no reason why not. The impact is fairly minimal, and most sites use it already. Then again, maybe all shirts should be white and all ice cream vanilla. Who needs choices.

Comment: The OP made the choice when he tagged (and explicitly asked for) javascript, NOT jQuery. "... using javascript" does not mean "... using jQuery" no matter what you hipsters seem to think.